# Lock screen background missing on Lock click and no spinning icon on restart/shutdown (Annivesary update)

Tags: windows-10

When I click `Lock`, I have no background image on that screen. I can see the date and time over a black background. When I go to the login screen, the background I set appears. The background only appears on the lock screen after a restart or when I boot up the computer.

In addition, when I restart or shutdown, there used to be a spinning icon next to the text `Restarting` and `Shutting Down`, but now there is nothing.

Are these features of the Anniversary update? If not, how can I fix? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!